# Excel logical statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to accomplish a certain task in excel. 
I want to practice 10 key skills.

I have typed numbers in column A(cells, A1,A2,A3,etc.).  I want to retype them in column B.  Then (if column B matches column A) would like to have the word "OK" appear in column c.  Can write the simple IF statement for A1=B1. Do not know how to make the statement automatically apply to other cells(i.e if A2=B2, A3 =B3, etc).

Thanks. CD

Comment: Make sure no dollar signs appear in the range specifications; then just copy paste.

Comment: It's hard to believe you can't figure this out with an internet search. At any rate, it's off-topic for SO, so I'm voting to close. Try SuperUser if you really need to.

Comment: @DougGlancy I believe this is 'technically' on-topic as it's excel-formula related which is a valid tag in SO.  Here is one of several [discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on/76767#76767) in meta that makes me believe this is still the case.  Is there another reason?

Comment: @PortlandRunner, nope, no other reason. My attitude towards this is about as mixed as the discussion you pointed to, i.e, very. In my judgement this was a basic enough question - how does an `IF` function work - that I thought it better suited to SU. But it's a gray line for sure.

Comment: @DougGlancy - Agreed :-)

Answer (score 2):

In cell 'C1'

```
=If(A1=B1,"OK", "")
```

Now drag this cell down col C until your last row.  Excel will auto increment A1 & B1 to A2 & B2 and so on... unless you use absolute referencing which is the dollar sign like this $A$1 for example.